# azure devOps Server 2020 - how to execute a batch file remotely?

Tags: azure-devops

I have installed a self-hosted agent on the azure devOps server. testing by creating a simple helloWorld.bat. in ADO release pipeline utility tasks via command line  to execute the helloWorld.bat. the hello World should display on the remote target server

Questions:

1. where should my helloWorld.bat reside at? On the ADO server or target server?
2. if on the target server, will my agent access the target path where the .bat sits on?
3. it doesn't make sense to me that the .bat should sit on the ADO cos how is it going to display on the hello World on the target server? What kind of ADO repo to store such scripts?

Comment: You can't just run commands in windows in other servers. You need to set up something like powershell remoting, ssh etc. If you need to run things in a remote target server, shouldn't the agent be there?

Comment: I am still in the midst of figuring out the process. so u mean, in the target, there should be a agent installed & the bat script should reside there too?  the agent that  is on the ADO server will communicate with the target agent to trigger the file? how to test the agent to agent communication as a baby then ?

Answer (score 1):

Azure DevOps has a concept of Azure Pipeline Agents, which are responsible for executing whatever actions your pipelines are doing. With Azure DevOps Server, you can either install the agents on the same server running the Azure DevOps installation, or the target servers you want Azure DevOps to deploy (or do other things) into. With the use case you are describing, installing the pipeline agents to target servers probably makes life easier; if you have the agents on the same machine where Azure DevOps Server is, you need to enable some way for the agents to interact with the target server. Powershell remoting  is one option.

If you are able to install pipeline agents to the target servers, you want to store the file (and whatever you want to execute in future) into Azure DevOps version control repositories (Git or TFVC). When executing a pipeline with an agent, the agent will clone the repository (or repositories) associated  to the pipeline and execute the tasks on pipeline with the privileges configured to the agent. In this case, the agent would download the bat, and execute it in the target server with whatever privileges you configured the agent with. You could do the same with agents installed on the Azure DevOps Server, but then you'd have to store the file to the remote server, or copy and execute it over the powershell remoting with something like this task: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines?view=azure-devops

For general information on self-hosted agents, refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install, and with Windows agents to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops

If you are using or planning to use pipelines created with the UI, do check the deployment group usage and configuration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops . If you are planning to implement pipelines with yaml, just configure agent pools for remote machines.

Comment: reading on about Powershell on target, do you need a target agent to be installed? or follow the steps provided to install the WinRM :https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines?view=azure-devops-2020  , as my machines are domain joined, i need to attempt the installation of the WinRM from this link :https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-winrm?view=azure-devops-2020.  need any file share, as from the abv links , need to enable file and printer sharing. what happens if client doesn't allow?

Comment: With WinRM-based tasks you don't need to have pipeline agents on target servers and you should not need anything but enablin the winrm on target server (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/installation-and-configuration-for-windows-remote-management). The mentioned tasks will copy and execute the bat on target server. If you cannot enable winrm on target server, do check if you can install agent there and have port 443 open on Azure DevOps server machine.

Comment: hi JukkaK, you mention: "do check if you can install agent there and have port 443 open on Azure DevOps server machine "..... .once i install the target agent what is the next step to do? still put my helloWorld.bat on target? what template to use in azure pipeline agent task to allow ADO agent talk to the target agent to let the target agent execute the .bat script on its server?

Comment: i am thinking the helloWorld.bat cannot be seated at the target. that is because, the helloWorld.bat has to be 1st version control but storing it on the ADO server Repo. so it needs to be copy over to the target. in that case must some sort of a file share be open or at least WinRM is a more firewall friend tools to convince client to allow it ?  i am still cannot wrap my head around how the 2 agent talks to each other.... .

Comment: my default pool got my self- hosted agent and target agent, during setting up my pipeline stage task, why can't i just specifically choose my target agent to run the helloWorld.bat ?

Comment: Well, you need to get that file to the target server somehow. With agent on the target server and a pipeline executing on that agent, the agent clones the git repo where you have the file to the target server, and executes tasks you have in your pipeline (which should include execution of the file). In this scenario, the agent polls Azure DevOps Server on port 443, handles cloning the repository, and executing the pipeline, so no file share or WinRM connection is needed.

Comment: If you run the pipeline on an agent installed in the Azure DevOps Server, the agent needs to access the target machine somehow. Copying the file to the target server could be done via a file share, but you'd still need to execute it somehow. WInRM would be the obvious choice in this case.

Comment: If you have installed an agent to the target server and registered it to the default pool, then you can of course use it. But in this scenario, if your default pool has other agents that are installed in the machine hosting Azure DevOps Server, you'd also have figure out a way for your pipeline to select the one agent installed to the target server. There are multiple ways to achieve this, but just using another agent pool or deployment group would be the easiest. All in all, I think we are reaching the point where you need to do some trials to get a hang on how pipelines work.

Comment: hi JuKKak, i have successfully tried using the method by installing a target agent and it has registered itself on the ADO Server agent default pool. A release pipeline was created and using the target agent to perform the execution task (to execute helloWorld.bat). and yes, the target agent does clone the ADO server Repo over to the target server and executed the helloWorld.bat on target.

Comment: JuKKak, regarding the firewall, ports opening, 443 is actually the https secure port that needs to be open on ADO Server or target Server? how does the traffic goes? from ADO Server ( 1 way ) or 2 way , meaning both side needs to be open. My testing vm is using http.  so when i install my target agent , i was able to connect to the ADO http url  (default 8080) to complete my target agent installation. The pipeline was able to complete without any port opening on the target server too. As the target agent was able to clone the ADO repo over to its server.

Comment: Pipeline agents polls the server, so 443 open on server for inbound traffic, as described in the documentation. I think http works as well, but is certainly not recommended. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#communication

Comment: sorry JuKKak, don't really gets you. 80/ 443 to be open on ADO Server for inbound traffic? what you mean by saying " pipeline agents polls the server" ? you mean the target agent will initial the communication to the ADO server ( during installation ) and also during the pipeline tasks execution in a pull model as explain in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops-2020&tabs=browser     --> Communication with TFS

Comment: there is no need to open 80/ 443 at the target agent server since they are seated behind the firewall? sorry i am abit slow on firewall issue.

Comment: The communication pattern is actually quite well described in just that documentation page, and especially on that picture. So, if there are firewalls between the servers, you need to allow (target server) -> 80/443 -> (ADO server), as the pipeline agent on target server initiates the communication through 80/443 towards ADO server.

Comment: appreciate Jukkak for taking the extra help to explain how one should interpret the traffic flow accurately. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*1. where should my helloWorld.bat reside at? On the ADO server or
target server?*

On the target server. If your build agent is on the ADO server and helloWorld.bat, you have to copy it into the target one with [Windows Machine File Copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=azure-devops)

*2. if on the target server, will my agent access the target path where
the .bat sits on?*

Yes, you have to use some use that will have access. Consider using [PowerShell on Target Machines task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines?view=azure-devops)

*3. it doesn't make sense to me that the .bat should sit on the ADO cos
how is it going to display on the hello World on the target server?
What kind of ADO repo to store such scripts?*

You can use GIT. Link your repo as an artifact to your release then you can perform any actions from the release work folder. [Artifact sources - TFVC, Git, and GitHub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#artifact-sources---tfvc-git-and-github)

Comment: thank you Shamrai Aleksander..... . think i have to wrap my head around all the info given so far from all the expertise. will feedback the progress of my " use case " !